# android: Dynamic checkbox inside listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I need to display a checkbox dynamically in a listview (one checkbox per list item) based on menu option selction.

Please suggest me the best way to implement it.

Thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well here is an example, how to achieve it:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-multiple-choice-example

Comment: thank you pkk; i need to display the listview without checkbox initially, then based on user selection i need to display the checkbox in the existing listview.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a custom View, you can place a checkbox within that view. Then in the getView, you can check the sentinel to determine if that check box should be VISIBLE or GONE